# Missing Nuget packages error in ,NET core 3.1 app

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

**I am using VS code and not Visual Studio to run my .NET core 3.1 web app.**

I have a .NET core 3.1 app. As I am using an Client VDI machine ( It is using Win 7 SP1 operating system) which is blocking the Nuget.Org URL currently.
so as a work around, I have copied over all the Nuget package into an folder in my VDI and updated the path in the Nuget.Config.
But still I am getting below
Missing Package" error. My App do not DIRECTLY depends on these packages.

[image]

following is my Nuget.Config file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!-- add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" / -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="C:\NugetPackageDownloadLocation" / >
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

any help will be appriciated.

Comment: This seems like a scenario where you would build this somewhere that has access to the 
traditional Nuget resources and deploy to this restricted environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a package source via the CLI?  Given how .NET Core handles transitive dependencies getting all the packages required for a relatively complex solution might be tricky.

```
nuget sources Add -Name "MyServer" -Source \\myserver\packages
```